# Cloning an array in Javascript/Typescript

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

I have array of two objects:

```
genericItems: Item[] = [];
backupData: Item[] = [];
```

I am populating my HTML table with `genericItems`data. The table is modifiable. There is a reset button to undo all changes done with `backUpData`. This array is populated by a service:

```
getGenericItems(selected: Item) {
this.itemService.getGenericItems(selected).subscribe(
  result => {
     this.genericItems = result;
  });
     this.backupData = this.genericItems.slice();
  }
```

My idea was that, the user changes will get reflected in first array and second array can be used as backup for reset operation. The issue I am facing here is when the user modifies the table (`genericItems[])` the second array `backupData` also gets modified.

How is this happening and how to prevent this?

Comment: Looks like you made a shallow copy of the array. It sounds like you're modifying the objects they were holding and seeing the changes. You need to make a deep copy or come up with a different way to represent your data.

Comment: They are pointing to the same reference. If you return a new array using a library like lodash or similar, you won't have that problem.

Comment: `slice()` will create new object from another array I guess...

Comment: The second array is being modified because rather than creating a new array you are merely referencing the original one. If your using type script and ES6 you can create a copy like this
this.backupData = [...this.genericItems]  this will create a copy of the array. Hope that helps!

Comment: slice() would work, yes. At any rate, what you need to do is use functional programming and return a new array that does not modify or point to the original one.

Comment: @MolikMiah I do not believe that is correct. `genericItems.slice()` creates a new array, but it contains the exact same objects. So `[...this.genericItems]` would effectively do the same thing, no?

Comment: slice should work, but only for one-dimensional array. If you two-dimensional array it is not gonna work.

Comment: No it's one dimensional array

Comment: @FrankModica you're right, both methods should create a copy of the array rather than reference the original array. it is strange that the .slice() is not working! Arun Raj - if you're still having trouble can you please give us an example of what the data looks like in the array and when you say backupData gets modified, in what way does it get modified?

Comment: @MolikMiah I'm saying that `slice` takes an array and copies each reference into a new array. So the old array and new array are actually different, but the objects inside are exactly the same. So it should be the same as doing `[...array]`

Comment: can you show us the html ? can you make sure the user is modifying genericItems[], not backupData[]? That is the only mistake I can think of.

Answer (score 262, accepted):

**Clone an object:**

`const myClonedObject = Object.assign({}, myObject);`

**Clone an Array:**

- ***Option 1***  if you have an array of primitive types:

`const myClonedArray  = Object.assign([], myArray);`

- ***Option 2*** - if you have an array of objects:

```
const myArray= [{ a: 'a', b: 'b' }, { a: 'c', b: 'd' }];
const myClonedArray = [];
myArray.forEach(val => myClonedArray.push(Object.assign({}, val)));
```

Comment: If your array is an array of objects, (not primitive types), then you need to go one level deeper with your shallow copy. For me the solution was to iterate through the array and clone the objects. I.e. `const myArray= [{ a: 'a', b: 'b' }, { a: 'c', b: 'd' }];
const myClonedArray = [];
myArray.map(val => myClonedArray.push(Object.assign({}, val)));`.  An alternative solution for a proper deep copy would be for JSON serialization as mentioned in other answers.

Comment: @mumblesNZ, if you're really talking about a deep copy, two levels won't suffice either. You'd have to use something like Lodash's `_.cloneDeep(obj)`. JSON serialization would work, like you said, but that's a very roundabout way to do it.

Comment: The option 2 part of this answer works fine for an object that holds primitives. If an array element contains a value which is an array or object, deep copy helps as @user2683747 mentioned.

Comment: A helpful reference about deep and shallow copy.. https://www.techmeet360.com/blog/playing-with-javascript-object-clone/

Answer (score 148):

**Cloning Arrays and Objects in javascript have a different syntax**. Sooner or later everyone learns the difference the hard way and end up here.

In **Typescript** and **ES6** you can use the spread operator for array and object:

```
const myClonedArray  = [...myArray];  // This is ok for [1,2,'test','bla']
                                      // But wont work for [{a:1}, {b:2}]. 
                                      // A bug will occur when you 
                                      // modify the clone and you expect the 
                                      // original not to be modified.
                                      // The solution is to do a deep copy
                                      // when you are cloning an array of objects.
```

To do a deep copy of an object you need an external library:

```
import {cloneDeep} from 'lodash';
const myClonedArray = cloneDeep(myArray);     // This works for [{a:1}, {b:2}]
```

The spread operator works on object as well but it will only do a shallow copy (first layer of children)

```
const myShallowClonedObject = {...myObject};   // Will do a shallow copy
                                               // and cause you an un expected bug.
```

To do a deep copy of an object you need an external library:

```
 import {cloneDeep} from 'lodash';
 const deeplyClonedObject = cloneDeep(myObject);   // This works for [{a:{b:2}}]
```

Comment: Ah! The penny drops! Time to stop using the spread operator to clone arrays of objects

Comment: const myClonedArray  = [...myArray] is working for [{a:1}, {b:2}].

Comment: No it does not. try modifying your cloned item and it will also modify the original. what you have is copy by reference and not value.

Comment: For deepcloning can also use "Object.assign(Object.create(Object.getPrototypeOf(obj)), obj);" instead of using an external library.

Comment: This is the answer that works for array of arrays

Answer (score 39):

Using map or other similar solution do not help to clone deeply an array of object. 
An easier way to do this without adding a new library is using JSON.stringfy and then JSON.parse.

In your case this should work :

```
this.backupData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(genericItems));
```

- When using the last version of JS/TS, installing a large library like lodash for just one/two function is a bad move. You will heart your app performance and in the long run you will have to maintain the library upgrades! check https://bundlephobia.com/result?p=lodash@4.17.15
- For small objet lodash cloneDeep can be faster but for larger/deeper object json clone become faster. So in this cases you should not hesitate to use it. check  https://www.measurethat.net/Benchmarks/Show/6039/0/lodash-clonedeep-vs-json-clone-larger-object and for infos https://v8.dev/blog/cost-of-javascript-2019#json
- The inconvenient is that your source object must be convertible to JSON.

Comment: The best solution to clone deeply an array of objects without using any new libraries

Answer (score 19):

try the following code:

```
this.cloneArray= [...this.OriginalArray]
```

Comment: While the spread operator is helpful, it will only be a shallow copy if the array contains objects

Answer (score 6):

The following line in your code creates a new array, copies all object references from `genericItems` into that new array, and assigns it to `backupData`:

```
this.backupData = this.genericItems.slice();
```

So while `backupData` and `genericItems` are different arrays, they contain the same exact object references.

You could bring in a library to do deep copying for you (as @LatinWarrior mentioned).

But if `Item` is not too complex, maybe you can add a `clone` method to it to deep clone the object yourself:

```
class Item {
  somePrimitiveType: string;
  someRefType: any = { someProperty: 0 };

  clone(): Item {
    let clone = new Item();

    // Assignment will copy primitive types

    clone.somePrimitiveType = this.somePrimitiveType;

    // Explicitly deep copy the reference types

    clone.someRefType = {
      someProperty: this.someRefType.someProperty
    };

    return clone;
  }
}
```

Then call `clone()` on each item:

```
this.backupData = this.genericItems.map(item => item.clone());
```

Answer (score 6):

### **Array copy explained - Deep & Shallow**

Below code might help you to copy the first level objects

```
let original = [{ a: 1 }, {b:1}]
const copy = [ ...original ].map(item=>({...item}))
```

**so for below case, values remains intact**

```
copy[0].a = 23
console.log(original[0].a) //logs 1 -- value didn't change voila :)
```

**Fails for this case**

```
let original = [{ a: {b:2} }, {b:1}]
const copy = [ ...original ].map(item=>({...item}))
copy[0].a.b = 23;
console.log(original[0].a) //logs {b: 23} -- lost the original one :(
```

---

> **Try lodash separate ES module - cloneDeep:**
>
> I would say go for lodash [`cloneDeep`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#cloneDeep) API ( *This can be
> installed as a **separate module**, reduced code footprint for treeshaking* ) which helps you to copy the objects
> inside objects completely dereferencing from original one's.
> As another option you can rely on `JSON.stringify` & `JSON.parse`
> methods to dereference quickly and performant too.

**Refer documentation:** https://github.com/lodash/lodash

**Individual Package** : https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.clonedeep

Answer (score 6):

you can use map function

```
 toArray= fromArray.map(x => x);
```

Answer (score 5):

**Clone an object / array (without reference) in a very powerful way**

You can get deep-copy of your `object` / `array` using `@angular-devkit`.

```
import { deepCopy } from '@angular-devkit/core/src/utils/object';

export class AppComponent {

  object = { .. some object data .. }
  array = [ .. some list data .. ]

  constructor() {
     const newObject = deepCopy(this.object);
     const newArray = deepCopy(this.array);
  }
}
```

Comment: Excellent, this works, a native solution for people who don't prefer or have `loaddash` dependency

Comment: That did it, thank you very much. I'm amazed as to why the spread operator or other methods like slice, etc. didn't work. assigning the destination array to the source array, always changed the source array too, what a disaster.

Comment: @Nexus An array of "objects" (object as in `{ ... }`) is not actually an array of objects. It's subtle, but an array of objects is actually an array of references. As a real world metaphor, think of "objects" as websites on the web: in that case an "array of objects" would __actually__ be an array url addresses. The array does not contain the websites themselves, and If you copy the array, you will get a copy of the urls. If one website owner changes their homepage, you would "see" it from both arrays. (cont...)

Comment: _(...cont)_ The websites (objects) were __not__ copied because they are not in the array to begin with. The objects are somewhere else (in computer memory) - you don't need to know because the javascript engine keeps track of that - just like a website resides on some server at a physical address somewhere - but you don't need to know where exactly since you can reference it with the url. Clearly if you wanted to copy the websites themselves you would need a lot more code to do the job, which is why other smart people have made such "deepCopy" methods.

Answer (score 3):

I have the same issue with primeNg DataTable. After trying and crying, I've fixed the issue by using this code.

```
private deepArrayCopy(arr: SelectItem[]): SelectItem[] {
    const result: SelectItem[] = [];
    if (!arr) {
      return result;
    }
    const arrayLength = arr.length;
    for (let i = 0; i <= arrayLength; i++) {
      const item = arr[i];
      if (item) {
        result.push({ label: item.label, value: item.value });
      }
    }
    return result;
  }
```

For initializing backup value

```
backupData = this.deepArrayCopy(genericItems);
```

For resetting changes

```
genericItems = this.deepArrayCopy(backupData);
```

The magic bullet is to recreate items by using `{}` instead of calling constructor.
I've tried `new SelectItem(item.label, item.value)` which doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

the easiest way to clone an array is

```
backUpData = genericItems.concat();
```

This will create a new memory for the array indexes

Comment: This doesn't create a new memory for `backUpData`. `backUpData` still holds reference of `genericItems`.

Answer (score 2):

If your items in the array are not primitive you can use spread operator to do that.

```
this.plansCopy = this.plans.map(obj => ({...obj}));
```

Complete answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/47776875/5775048

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
[https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#clone][1]

var objects = [{ 'a': 1 }, { 'b': 2 }];

var shallow = _.clone(objects);
console.log(shallow[0] === objects[0]);
// => true
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you may have made a mistake as to where you are doing the copy of an Array. Have a look at my explanation below and a slight modification to the code which should work in helping you reset the data to its previous state.

**In your example i can see the following taking place:**

- you are doing a request to get generic items
- after you get the data you set the results to the this.genericItems
- directly after that you set the backupData as the result

Am i right in thinking you don't want the 3rd point to happen in that order?

**Would this be better:**

- you do the data request
- make a backup copy of what is current in this.genericItems
- then set genericItems as the result of your request

**Try this:**

```
getGenericItems(selected: Item) {
  this.itemService.getGenericItems(selected).subscribe(
    result => {
       // make a backup before you change the genericItems
       this.backupData = this.genericItems.slice();

       // now update genericItems with the results from your request
       this.genericItems = result;
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

array level cloning solutions didn't work for me, added this clone utility in typescript which does a deeper clone that worked in my case

```
export function cloneArray<T>(arr: T[]): T[] {
  return arr.map((x) => Object.assign({}, x))
}
```

by "didn't work" i meant, that if i passed an array to a function `[...arr]` or `Object.assign([], arr)` or `arr.splice()` it was still mutating the original array

Answer (score 0):

Looks like what you want is **Deep Copy** of the object. Why not use `Object.assign()`? No libaries needed, and its a one-liner :)

```
getGenericItems(selected: Item) {
    this.itemService.getGenericItems(selected).subscribe(
        result => {
            this.genericItems = result;
            this.backupDate = Object.assign({}, result); 
            //this.backupdate WILL NOT share the same memory locations as this.genericItems
            //modifying this.genericItems WILL NOT modify this.backupdate
        });
}
```

More on `Object.assign()`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

Comment: This will do the same thing as `slice()`. It creates a new array, but copies the object references from the old array.

Comment: Also, I think it should be `Object.assign([], result)`. Otherwise, I think you'll lose the `length` property (and maybe some other things).

Answer (score -1):

### **Try this**

```
const returnedTarget = Object.assign(target, source);
```

and pass empty array to target

in case complex objects this way works for me

`$.extend(true, [], originalArray)` in case of array

`$.extend(true, {}, originalObject)` in case of object