# How to clone array of objects TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I tried this approach:

```
this.plans = [];
this.plansCopy = [...this.plans];
```

Seems it does not work cause returns duplictions.

Comment: What do you mean it returns duplications?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The spread operator returns the individual items of the array. If these are already objects, then it's returning the *references* to those objects. It's the `[]` part that is creating a new array. Thus you have a new array, but it will still contain the same object references, so `this.plans[0].oper()` will call `this.plansCopy[0].oper()` at the same time as well.

Instead you need to clone each individual object. There are a lot of different ways to do this (create deep copy of the array or individual objects). If you only need one level of cloning you can do:

```
this.plansCopy = this.plans.map(obj => ({...obj}));
```

This will create a new array where each element is a copy of each object.

Comment: Can you exent answer more, because you missed main

Comment: What does it mean? `map(obj => ({...obj}));`? you mean? map(obj => ({ return obj})); ?

Comment: @Alice what do you mean I missed main? Can you update your question with an example of duplications that are returned?

Comment: @Alice `.map(obj => ({...obj}))` is the same as `.map(obj => { return {...obj}; })`

Comment: Ou, sorry, I thought differently about `...obj`

Comment: "..." is a [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

Answer (score 10):

This is well answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44808882/cloning-an-array-in-javascript-typescript). The main problem is that you can have the issue of *copying* a reference, rather than *duplicating* it, at deeper levels of the array. If you know you only have simple objects, you can also use

```
const newArray = Array.from(oldArray);
```

which I find clearer than the spread operator.

However, if you don't know how deep the complexity of your array goes (i.e. how deeply nested you might have a non-simple type) the generic answer seems to be

```
this.backupData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(genericItems));
```

As this will go *all* the way down the array's objects, and build them back up -- cloning for the general case.