# Angular 6 HttpClient assign resulting payload to array

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular-httpclient, angular-arrays

I am attempting to do a get call in angular the call itself works as I can put a log in the subscribe and see the returned data the issue I am having is I can't seem to assign the data to my existing array (Currently Empty) and as the code below is of type `Event[]`. I have tried using a map on the data array which is also of type `Event[]` but no luck and the same with push although I believe this is because you can't push an array. I am sure there is something simple I am missing or can't find.

Here is the call I am making and bellow that the Event model.

```
this.httpClient.get<Event[]>('http://127.0.0.1:5555/events-get').subscribe((data) => this.events = data); 


export class Event {
    constructor(public name: String, public date: Date, public time: Date) {}
}
```

I am new to angular so I could be doing it all wrong any help is much appreciated.

**EDIT**

I have dome some more research but still no joy maybe this is something to do with having it in subscribe. [I tried some of the array clone solutions from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44808882/create-a-clone-of-an-array-in-typescript/46935425)

**EDIT 2**

Looking further I see that the contents of subscribe are a function is there something I am missing with scope does my `this.events` need passing in some way, it's set at the class level.

**EDIT 3**

```
import { Event } from '../shared/event.model';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http'

@Injectable()
export class AdminService {
    eventsChanged = new Subject<Event[]>();

    private events: Event[] = [];

    constructor(private http: Http, private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

    getEvents() {
        this.httpClient.get<Event[]>('http://127.0.0.1:5555/events-get')
        .pipe(
            map(
                (data: Event[]) => data.map(event => {
                // may need to coerce string to Date types
                    return new Event(event.name, event.date, event.time)
                })
            )
        )
        .subscribe((events: Event[]) => this.events = events);

        console.log(this.events);
        return this.events;
}
```

I am then using this call in my component this hasn't changed from when it worked using a local array of `Event[]`.

```
 this.events = this.adminService.getEvents();
```

Comment: I see there are three votes to close, did I not give enough information? If not what do you need?

Comment: In your original example, if you instead log inside the `subscribe()`, are you seeing the data you expect? `subscribe((data) => console.log(data));`

Comment: Yes I see the json posted from the server it's just not saving to the other array and both are shown as type `Event[]`

Comment: Can you clarify the intent/need for the multiple `rxjs` operators? I'm familiar with seeing the `map` operator in code that imports and uses the `HttpModule`, but one of the advantages of the `HttpClientModule` is that it handles type-checking and serialization for you.

The example [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mxetee) I provide in my solution below removes the `rxjs` operators and is still able to correctly handle serialization to the specified type.

Comment: I don't know I am only half way through the angular course and the instructor likes to show you multiple implementations then change them later showing you how to do it badly then how it should be done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The base issue is you are attempting to return the `Event[]` data from your `AdminService.getEvents()` method prior to `httpClient.get<Event[]>()` resolving/emitting and `subscribe()` executing/assigning, that is why it is always returning an empty array. This is simply the asynchronous nature of `HttpClient` and RxJS.

```
@Injectable()
export class AdminService {
// ...

getEvents() {
    // this happens after console.log() and return this.events
    .subscribe((events: Event[]) => this.events = events);

    // this executes before get()/subscribe() resolves, so empty [] is returned
    console.log(this.events);
    return this.events;
}
```

Instead return the `get<Event[]>().pipe()` instead for the `@Component` to call and utilize:

```
import { Event } from '../shared/event.model';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Subject, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http'

@Injectable()
export class AdminService {
  eventsChanged = new Subject<Event[]>();

  constructor(private http: Http, private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

  getEvents(): Observable<Event[]> {
    return this.httpClient.get<Event[]>('http://127.0.0.1:5555/events-get')
      .pipe(
        map(
          (data: Event[]) => data.map(event => {
            // may need to coerce string to Date types
            return new Event(event.name, event.date, event.time)
           })
        )
      );
  }
```

Component:

```
@Component({ /* ... */ })
export class EventsComponent implements OnInit {
  events$: Observable<Event[]>;

  constructor(private adminService: AdminService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.events$ = this.adminService.getEvents();
  }
}
```

Template with async pipe:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let event of events$ | async">{{event.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

Or:

```
@Component({})
export class EventsComponent implements OnInit {
  events: Event[] = [];

  constructor(private adminService: AdminService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.adminService.getEvents()
      .subscribe(events => this.events = events);
  }
}
```

Template:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let event of events">{{event.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

On a side note, `HttpClient` with a type will not automatically create instances of `Event` class from a typed `get()`, it is objects with a set type. You could use the RxJS `map` operator in combination with `Array.prototype.map` to create an instance of class `Event` for each `Event` typed object return from `get<Event[]>`. Also be careful with naming it `Event` as it could conflict with an existing symbol [Event](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.dom.d.ts#L4846).

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Sorry but same issue this.events is still empty

Comment: When/where exactly are you trying to use `this.events`, if you are attempting to log it prior resolving it will be undefined.

Comment: it's not undefined it's empty I define it at the top shown as `[]` the get runs in a function that returns this.events

Comment: You please would need to show how you are using this.events and calling the get() in your component exactly. You are absolutely sure you are getting data from the server? There must be something else going on.

Comment: @bobthemac I've updated the answer, you simply cannot return `this.events` from the service like that as it resolves before `subscribe()` executes. Instead return the `Observable<Event[]>` instead and execute the subscribe in the @Component. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your help, I did try that but it broke some other parts looked at the code from a tutorial and just created a set function and passed `events` to that and then set `this.events` probably not the best but it works. Thanks again I will look at your code more in depth later.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems with your code.

> As per your code, you are unable to understand the RxJS Observable. You call subscribe, when you are finally ready to listen. So your `getEvents()` method should not subscribe, rather return the observable. i.e.

```
getEvents(): Observable<Event[]> {
  return this.httpClient
    .get<Event[]>("http://127.0.0.1:5555/events-get")
    .pipe(
      map(data =>
        data.map(event => new Event(event.name, event.date, event.time))
      )
    );
}
```

Since you have used

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let event of events$ | async">{{event.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

The `async` pipe does the `subscribe` for you in the html. Just expose the `events$` like you have already done in the `ngOnInit()`.

> I wouldn't define my interface as `Event` because `Event` is already part of *RxJS*.

Also, since you are calling your console.log outside the subscription, it will always be null, unless you add a `tap` from *RxJS* like this.

```
import { Event } from "../shared/event.model";
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Http, Response } from "@angular/http";
import { Subject } from "rxjs";
import { map, tap } from "rxjs/operators";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";

@Injectable()
export class AdminService {
  constructor(private http: Http, private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

  getEvents(): Observable<Event[]> {
    return this.httpClient
      .get<Event[]>("http://127.0.0.1:5555/events-get")
      .pipe(
        map(data =>
          data.map(event => new Event(event.name, event.date, event.time))
        ),
        tap(console.log)
      );
  }
}
```

> Also, why are you calling both `Http` and `HttpClient`. Either use the client or http.

*Happy Coding*

Comment: I am part way through an angular course, haven't got to observables yet. I haven't used async in the template, and haven't gotten to the upgrade everything to httpclient part either.  Thanks for the answer though some good point in their all taken onboard.

Answer (score 0):

From reviewing your third edit, I think the `map/pipe` issues are a red-herring and the core issue is the implementation of an asynchronous `http` call inside of a public method signature that behaves synchronously, i.e., `getEvents()`.

For example, I would expect this [code snippet](https://repl.it/@ericksoen/WeeLightblueGravity) to behave similarly, in that the method is able to immediately return `this.events`, whose value is still an empty array, and then proceed with executing the specified behavior inside of the asynchronous `setTimeout`

```
private events: Event[] = [];
private event1: Event = new Event("event1", "date", "time");
private event2: Event = new Event("event2", "date", "time");
public getEvents(): Event[] {
   setTimeout(() => {
     this.events = [..., event1, event2];
   }, 5000);

   return this.events;
}
```

For your code example, are you able to get the desired results with a code implementation similar to this. Complete functional implementation available on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mxetee):

```
export class AdminService {
...
   public getEvents(): Observable<Event[]> {
   // Returns an observable
   return this.httpClient.get<Event[]>(url);
  }
}

export class EventComponent {

constructor(private adminService: AdminService) {}
    public events: Event[] = [];

    ngOnInit() {
        // Subscribe to the observable and when the asynchronous method
        // completes, assign the results to the component property.
        this.adminService.getEvents().subscribe(res => this.events = res);
    }
}
```