# Spread syntax in an array of objects

Tags: javascript, object, multidimensional-array, ecmascript-6

I have a question regarding the spread syntax and an array of objects.

Having an array of objects like:

```
const array = [{age:50}, {age:27}]
```

According to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54138394/6781511, using the spread syntax will result in `referencedArray` having a shallow copy of `array`.

```
const referencedArray = [...array]
```

What then is the difference between using the spread syntax and not using it?

```
const referencedArray = [...array]
```

vs

```
const referencedArray = array
```

Comment: Using the spread operator will make a shallow copy, not using it... won't. `clonedArray` is a bad name in that case, it's just another reference to the same object.

Comment: With spread syntax (it's not an "operator") there will be *two* arrays, with the simple assignment there's just one.

Comment: `const referencedArray1 = [...array]; const referencedArray2 = array; array.push("hello"); console.log(referencedArray1, referencedArray2);`

Answer (score 1):

See the following example.

When you make a shallow copy, assigning to an element of the original doesn't affect the clone. When you don't make a copy, assigning to the original affects the other reference.

Since it's a shallow copy, assigning to properties of the objects in the array affects all of them. Only the array was copied by spreading, not the objects.

```js
const array = [{age:50}, {age:27}];
const clonedArray = [...array];
const notClonedArray = array;

array[0] = {age: 100};
array[1].age = 30;
console.log("Original:", array);
console.log("Cloned:", clonedArray);
console.log("Not cloned:", notClonedArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

The objects within the arrays have the same reference in both, but in the spread scenario, modifying the array will not affect the original.

```
const array = [{ name: 'Joe' }, { name: 'Paul' }];
const spreadArray = [...array];
const cloneArray = array;

spreadArray[3] = { name: 'Bob' };
console.log(array); //  [{ name: 'Joe' }, { name: 'Paul' }];

cloneArray[3] = { name: 'Bob' };
console.log(array); //  [{ name: 'Joe' }, { name: 'Paul' }, { name: 'Bob'} ];
```

That's because `cloneArray` is assigned by reference to `array`, while `spreadArray` is assigned to a new array with the same elements as `array`. That's also why

```
cloneArray === array; // true
spreadArray === array; // false
```